# SQL sync count with table group result

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have multiple tables in my SQL Server database.

I have one table [Tatkal_Merge] which has fields like filename,C_srno,Scan,etc. [c_srno is the secondary key]

The second table Collation_Data has details like srno,filename, dispatchcount, totalcount etc. [srno is the primary key]

The totalcount is the total number of records in tatkalmerge table.

There are many other fields in both tables but not relevant to this question.

Whenever the customer scans a barcode in winForm and the update is successful I update [Tatkal_Merge] with  scan value 'Y' and increment the Collation_Data dispatch count using stored procedure

```
update [Tatkal_Merge] set [DScan]=@scan,[DScanBy]=@scanBy,[DScanTime]=getdate() where Dscan='N' and [wl_barcode]=@wl

if(@@ROWCOUNT=1)
update Collation_Data set Dqty=Dqty+1 where srno=@C_srno
```

**Issue**

Sometimes due to some reason the Dispatch count is not correct by 1 or 2 customers.

**Requirement:**

1) Please guide why there is a discrepancy in the count. My guess is network issue between first and second command.

2) If am doing it the wrong what is the correct way of doing this?

3) If am doing it the right how to update the Table B in such scenario?

P.S.

Currently, I am updating the collation_Data using correlated subquery periodically,

```
update Collation_Data c
    set Dqty = (select count(*)
            from [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] m
            where m.Dscan = 'Y' and m.collation_code = c.collation_code
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do to isolate and troubleshoot:

1. Enclose both updates inside a transaction
2. Trap the @@ROWCOUNT on second update and if that is = 0 it means that the update wasnt succesfull and you could write all the important fields and variables into a logging table that might lead you to the culprit.
3. The main reason why the second update would fail would be if the @@ROWCOUNT from the first update was <> 1 or if it didnt find any row for that srno. Unlikely that it is a network issue.

Comment: it might be but what about value of  @wl ... how is it guaranteed to match only one row ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(@@ROWCOUNT=1)
```

this might be an issue if there are more matching rows to the first update of table [Tatkal_Merge]. Instead change it to:

```
if(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
update Collation_Data set Dqty=Dqty+1 where srno=@C_srno
```